# Bootstrap text-alignment based on size for buttons

Tags: javascript, css, class, twitter-bootstrap, button

I'm currently trying to dive through the documentation and seem to be hitting a dead end on something. I'm curious if there's a way to build in text-alignment at the size level for buttons etc without pulling buttons into separate divs.

For example, it would be great for the text-alignment to be right and left at md and lg so that the buttons are side by side and centered with the rest of the text. But in order to have it snap into place the only work around I've been able to find is to create an extra set of buttons that are hidden for the tablet sm and phone xs.

So the current work around I have is this but I would like to keep it to one set of buttons if possible. Thoughts?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs visible-sm text-center">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 mrg-B-lg">
            <div class="btn btn-primary btnChangeLogin" onClick="submitForm('changeLogin')">
                Change Login

           </div>
        </div>   
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
            <div class="btn btn-secondary btnLogOut" onClick="submitForm('logout')">
                Logout
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix hidden-xs hidden-sm text-center">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">

            <div class="btn btn-primary btnChangeLogin" onClick="submitForm('changeLogin')">
                Change Login
            </div>
        </div>   
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <div  class="btn btn-secondary btnLogOut" onClick="submitForm('log-out')">
                Logout
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it in Button Groups like this: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups